# Don’t forget to enter notes” - If they have not enter note by today and enter note the prior day

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two tables
Member table and Daily_Notes table.

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
```

Daily_notes table

```
class DailyNotes(models.Model):
    member= models.Foreignkey('Member')
    note=models.Charfield()
    date=models.Datetimefield(default="")
```

Daily note table contains daily entries

I need to filter datas, If user have not enter note by today and entered the prior day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve `Member`s that have filled in a `DailyNotes` item the previous day and not the current day with:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

Member.objects.filter(
    dailynotes__date__date=date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
).exclude(
    dailynotes__date__date=date.today()
)
```

Comment: Thank you , can you explain the query please ?

Comment: @sarathsathyan: we make one `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for the filter that will look if there is a `dailynotes` record for that member written with `date` yesterday, and we exclude (done through a subquery) `Member`s that have written a `dailynotes` object today.

Comment: Thank you so much @willemvanonsem, Can you also suggest some best resources for learning django advanced queries ?

Comment: @sarathsathyan: the [*making queries*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) of the Django documentation explains how to build queries